# lack of information in facebook oath json response in laravel 5

Tags: php, json, facebook-graph-api, oauth, laravel-5.1

I've got a code in Laravel 5 for signing in users with facebook.
I use laravel Socialite.
I added these lines in services.php

```
'facebook' => [
'client_id' => 'some-number',
'client_secret' => 'my-client-secret',
'redirect' => 'http://some-website/FB/login',
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
],
```

and this is my routes.php

```
Route::get('FB', 'AccountController@FB_redirect');
Route::get('FB/login', 'AccountController@FB');
```

and this is AccountController

```
public function FB_redirect() {
  return Socialite::with('facebook')->redirect();
}
public function FB() {
  $user = Socialite::with('facebook')->user();
  // Do your stuff with user data.
  dd($user);
}
```

when I get log from the redirected json it doesn't contain specific information like nickname and specially email .
here's the json

```
User {#195 ▼
+token:     "some-token"
  +id: "some-id"
  +nickname: null
  +name: " "
  +email: null
  +avatar: "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/some-number/picture?type=normal"
  +"user": array:2 [▼
       "name" => "some-name"
       "id" => "some-id"
    ]
  +"avatar_original": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/some-number/picture?width=1920"
```

}

all the permission are allowed in the http://developers.facebook.com

how can I get the full Json response with email and all other information.